# Use of a4j:jsFunction Within a Paginated OpenFaces 3 Datatable

Tags: datatable, ajax4jsf, openfaces

I've a paginated OpenFaces 3 datatable (using o:dataTablePaginator within a facet below the table) that has a column which contains an a4j:jsFunction tag (using RichFaces 4.1) to create (a differently named) JavaScript function within each row of the table. The JSF 2.1 page which contains the table is being deployed within an application onto Glassfish 3.1.

When I click the next page icon for the table, the datatable fails to update via AJAX with the OpenFaces AJAX "Loading..." message (with the "spinning" diamond) remaining displayed in the top right corner of the page. In Firebug, I can see the result of the OpenFaces AJAX Post being an error with the affected line 344 of ajaxUtil.js:

```
TypeError: xml.getElementsByTagName("partial-response")[0] is undefined
var childNodes = xml.getElementsByTagName("partial-response")[0].childNodes;
```

and the following error in IE Developer Tools:

```
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'childNodes'
          : object is null or undefined
```

I've been able to eliminate all other tags within the datatable being the cause of the problem except for this one:

```
<a4j:jsFunction id="cellUpdateFunction#{rowIndex}"
                name="updateCellStr#{rowIndex}"
                data="#{backingBean.getStrForRow(rowIndex)}" execute="@this"
                oncomplete="setCellText(#{rowIndex}, event.data);"/>
```

This creates a JavaScript function in a column cell (for each row of the table) that when called updates the text in the cell with the string stored for the cell within the backing bean.

Does anyone know whether this is a known issue and there is a workaround I've been unable to find? Otherwise, how would I go about writing similar functionality with OpenFaces AJAX as I expect that using only OpenFaces components would not break the AJAX call updating the OpenFaces datatable?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to use the nightly builds and check? You can find nightly builds here: http://openfaces.org/downloads/